# Replacing null values with zeroes in multiple columns [Spotfire]

Tags: spotfire

I have about 100 columns with some empty values that I would like to replace with zeroes.  I know how to do this with a single column using Calculate and Replace, but I wanted to see if there was a way to do this with multiple columns at once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could script it but it'd probably take you as long to write the script as it would to do it manually with a transformation. A better idea would be to fix it in the data source itself before you import it so SPOTFIRE doesn't have to do the transformation every time, which if you are dealing with a large amount of data, could hinder your performance.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  The empty values in these columns are actually coming from a pivot, not from a data source.  I was thinking there might be a way to perform the pivot and fill any empty values with zero.

Comment: Are there less columns before or after the pivot? If it's after, then obviously changing the values prior to the pivot would benefit you. i can't imagine 100+ columns prior to a pivot though.

Comment: There are much less columns before the pivot.  Goes from about 20 columns to 150 columns after the pivot.

Comment: then i would definitely calculate and replace before. If you set it to an arbitrary value it shouldn't mess up your pivot.